# Integrate $\int x \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I need your advice in integrating $\int ln(f(x)) dx = \int x \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx$, where $f(x)$ is a probability density function.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Integrate by parts. The rest is evident.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \log f(x)$$

So use that as "dv" in integration by parts.

Comment: $\int ln(f(x)) dx$ was my starting point and I am interested in that how can I leave the integral.

Comment: Suppose that $g$ is any function you know to not be integrable in elementary terms. Let $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$. Now you have $\int \log f(x) ~dx = \int g(x) dx$, which is hopeless. So there's not going to be any "general" answer for integrating the log of a density.

Comment: And maybe could I estimate it? As I see it is similar to the score function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_%28statistics%29

Comment: Sure, you can always estimate an integral. Whether the estimate will be tight enough to be worthwhile is a matter of luck and skill. Shakespeare put it well.
GLENDOWER: I can call spirits from the vasty deep. 
HOTSPUR: Why, so can I, or so can any man;
But will they come when you do call for them?